# How can I hide initial looped and filtered data until keyup using Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to set up a loop with a filter that binds data to the dom but the problem is that the loop shows all the data initially and then filters down as the user types into the input field. I want it have the loop so that the looped data *doesn't* appear until after the first keyup.  Here's my code (I'm using slim w/rails, fyi):

```
ul ng-controller="FindfriendsCtrl"
  li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:search" {{ friend.username }}
```

Comment: I think assign filtered data to friends intially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put a condition to hide your data initially like :

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in filteredData = (friends | filter:search)" ng-hide="filteredData==friends"> {{friend.username}}</li>
```

or if you want to hide the results each time your search variable is empty you can compare the length of both like :

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in filteredData = (friends | filter:search)" ng-hide="filteredData.length==friends.length"> {{friend.username}}</li>
```